Using an equalizer with a low (pre-out) signal
I would like to use an EQ between my preamp and the power amp, so the EQ would get a low, also variable volume signal all the time (from the pre-out output of the preamp) and would output the sound directly to a power amp.
Would this affect the sound in theory, compared to using a line level signal?
Let's say that the internal noise from the EQ, that is considerably more noticeable when connected directly to the power amp, is not an issue.
Maybe the EQ was built having in mind that it would always use line level signals, and is not as efficient with a low level signal, or there are some other factors that could influence the sound in a different way than with a fixed high level line signal.
Or there's nothing to worry about?

Can you describe what level (i.e., voltage) you consider to be "line level", and how it differs from the signal level your preamp delivers to your power amp?

I must admit I couldn't get a voltage reading when playing music (probably should use test files with constant sound, but I don't have them right now), but by "line level" I mean the "normal" level at which a cd player for example, or another source normally outputs the sound through RCA, please excuse me if the term is misleading :) and the preamp output level is lower, after volume control, so usually 1/3 of the "normal" level or less, I guess.

RCA connectors are much more common with home audio than for pro audio which makes me think this is a home audio question and therefore off topic. What kind of preamp and power amp are you using?

T+A P 1220 R and A 1500, the EQ is Kenwood GE-770. Not sure how using similar type of devices to reproduce sound in studio or at home changes the way they function (question was about the capabilities of an EQ to handle a lower level signal than probably it was designed for), but yes, my setup falls into home audio category. Thank you OwenM for a thorough answer including insight for examples of different use cases

The job of a preamp is to take the input signal, eg. a mic or an instrument, and pre amplify it to line level. Once a signal has gone through a preamp it's going to be within an order of magnitude of line level pretty much (if the gain settings are sensibly set).
Most audio processing happens in this signal 'band', an EQ is designed to work around roughly line level so there should be nothing to worry about.  Even if your signal after the preamp is about 1/3 of line level it should be absolutely fine and all working comfortably within spec. Line level is just a reference point really, and of course real world signals will be lower or higher than the nominal in almost every occasion. I don't think you have anything to worry about. You can always just push the preamp a little more to get a slightly better signal to the EQ.
Radically out of spec, ie driving the EQ directly from a guitar may have undesired consequences, but this would potentially be less due to the low level signal and more to do with the EQ not receiving a signal of expected output impedance more than something to do with levels. Even a very low signal with a near perfect (ie very low) output impedance should be processed satisfactorily with the usual EQ circuitry. Plugging a piezo mic directly into an EQ might sound odd, as although the EQ should be designed with a fairly high input impedance it is probably not expecting to receive a signal from a HUGE output impedance like a piezo mic's circuitry.
So for a preamp output interacting with an EQ input, you'll be fine even at significantly lower levels of signal, though if you feed it TOO weak a signal you might well run into other problems, usually a bit more low level noise because the EQ circuitries self-noise starts to become comparable to the level of the signal itself, but it really would need to be WAY too low for this to start being an issue with a half decently designed EQ processor.
But it sounds like the setup you have (though more clarification on exact setup, what you are amplifying etc. would be welcome) is perfectly correct and should perform well.
